# Python: self.assertEqual(a, b, msg) --> I want diff AND msg

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

If I call it like this, I see a nice diff:

```
self.assertEqual(a, b)
```

If I call it like this, I see the msg only:

```
self.assertEqual(a, b, msg)
```

Is there an easy way to show the diff AND the msg?

Implementing `assertEqual()` myself would work, but I ask myself if this is really the best way.

Plattform: Python2.7 and pytest 2.6.2.

Comment: pytest does this, I think..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using pytest, you could also use pytest's plain assertions instead of the unittest compatibility:

```
def test_foo():
    assert "abcdefg" == "abcde", "My message"
```

Output:

```
====================== FAILURES ======================
______________________ test_foo ______________________

    def test_foo():
>       assert "abcdefg" == "abcde", "My message"
E       AssertionError: My message
E       assert 'abcdefg' == 'abcde'
E         - abcdefg
E         ?      --
E         + abcde
```

Comment: Yes, I could do this. I have to discuss this with my team. Up to now we use self.assertFOO() methods.

Answer (score 10):

If you set [`longMessage` attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.longMessage) `True`, you will see both message.

Example:

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    longMessage = True  # <--

    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertEqual(1+2, 2, 'custom message')
```

output:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_foo (__main__.TestFoo)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 6, in test_foo
    self.assertEqual(1+2, 2, 'custom message')
AssertionError: 3 != 2 : custom message

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you, it works like a charm. I am happy :-)

Comment: For Python3 the default of longMessage has changed to the better default True: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.longMessage